# takePicture does nothing on some devices (cameraX)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, camera

On my camera application, the takePicture function does not work on some phones.

the list of known phones that do not work:

- Motorola moto e40 android 11
- realme C35 android 11
- realmec21y
- realme C25Y version of Android 11
- Samsung galaxy a03 android 13
- realme C25 Android 11

CameraFragment :

```
class CameraFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentCameraBinding? = null
    val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var cameraService: CameraService
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
    private val selector = QualitySelector.from(Quality.UHD, FallbackStrategy.higherQualityOrLowerThan(Quality.SD))
    private var videoCapture: VideoCapture<Recorder>? = null
    private var videoActiveRecording: Recording? = null
    private var picture = Picture()
    private var videoUri: Uri? = null
    private var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider? = null

    private val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
    private var backCamera = true

    private val delayLongClick: Long = 500
    private var isLongClick = false
    private var recordingInProgress = false

    private lateinit var windowManager: WindowManager

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        _binding = FragmentCameraBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ---- INIT ----
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        windowManager = WindowManager(view.context)
        initView()

        // ---- BUTTON ----
        binding.fragmentCameraTakePictureBtn.setOnTouchListener(
        object : OnTouchListener {
            private val mHandler = Handler()
            private val mRunnable = Runnable {
                isLongClick = true

                recordingVideo()

                setTimer(10000) {
                    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {}
                    override fun onFinish() {
                        binding.fragmentCameraRecordingVideoReticule.visibility = View.GONE
                        videoActiveRecording?.stop()
                        recordingInProgress = false
                    }
                }.start()
            }

            override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                when (event.action) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, delayLongClick)
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)

                        if (!isLongClick) takePicture()
                        isLongClick = false

                        if (recordingInProgress) {
                            videoActiveRecording?.stop()
                            recordingInProgress = false
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true
            }
        })

        binding.fragmentCameraChangeStateBtn.setOnClickListener {
            backCamera = !backCamera
            startCamera(backCamera)
        }
    }

    // ---------------------
    // INIT
    // ---------------------

    private fun initView() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            setTimer(100) { startCamera(backCamera) }
        }
    }

    // ---------------------
    // CAMERA
    // ---------------------

    private fun startCamera(backCamera: Boolean) {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
            cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            val metrics = windowManager.getCurrentWindowMetrics().bounds
            val screenAspectRatio = aspectRatio(metrics.width(), metrics.height())

            val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                .build()
                .also { it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.fragmentCameraPreviewView.surfaceProvider) }

            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                .build()

            val cameraSelector = if (backCamera) CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA else CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA

            try {
                cameraProvider?.unbindAll()

                val viewPort =  ViewPort.Builder(Rational(binding.fragmentCameraPreviewView.width, binding.fragmentCameraPreviewView.height), activity?.display?.rotation!!).build()
                val useCaseGroup = UseCaseGroup.Builder()
                    .addUseCase(preview)
                    .setViewPort(viewPort)
                    .addUseCase(imageCapture!!)
                    .build()
                cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, useCaseGroup)
            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

            //VIDEO
            val recorder = Recorder.Builder().setQualitySelector(selector).build()
            videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)

            try {
                // Bind use cases to camera
                cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(this, if (backCamera) CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA else CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA, preview, videoCapture)
            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))

        binding.fragmentCameraPreviewView.afterMeasured {
            val autoFocusPoint = SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory(1f, 1f)
                .createPoint(.5f, .5f)
            try {
                val autoFocusAction = FocusMeteringAction.Builder(
                    autoFocusPoint,
                    FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF
                ).apply {
                    //start auto-focusing after 2 seconds
                    setAutoCancelDuration(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                }.build()
                imageCapture?.camera?.cameraControl?.startFocusAndMetering(autoFocusAction)
            } catch (e: CameraInfoUnavailableException) {
                Log.d("ERROR", "cannot access camera", e)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun takePicture() {
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        imageCapture.takePicture(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()), object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
            override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                println(exception)
            }

            @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
            override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
                if (!backCamera) {
                    picture.bitmap = image.image?.toBitmap()!!.rotateImage(image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees.toFloat()).crop(binding.fragmentCameraPreviewView.height, binding.fragmentCameraPreviewView.width)!!.horizontalFlip()
                }
                else {
                    picture.bitmap = image.image?.toBitmap()!!.rotateImage(image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees.toFloat()).crop(binding.fragmentCameraPreviewView.height, binding.fragmentCameraPreviewView.width)!!
                }
                image.close()
            }
        })

    }

    private fun recordingVideo() {
        recordingInProgress = true
        val folder = File(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString() + File.separator + requireContext().getString(R.string.app_name))
        if (!folder.exists()) folder.mkdir()

        val outputFile = File(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString() + File.separator + requireContext().getString(R.string.app_name) + "/video.mp4")
        val fileOutputOptions = FileOutputOptions.Builder(outputFile).build()

        // 2. Configure Recorder and Start recording to the mediaStoreOutput.
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            videoActiveRecording = videoCapture!!.output
                .prepareRecording(requireContext(), fileOutputOptions)
                .withAudioEnabled()
                .start(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()), videoRecordingListener)
        }
    }

    private val videoRecordingListener = Consumer<VideoRecordEvent> { event ->
        when (event) {
            is VideoRecordEvent.Finalize -> if (event.hasError()) {
                printl("video recording error")
            } else {
                this.videoUri = event.outputResults.outputUri
                val videoFile = File(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString() + File.separator + requireContext().getString(R.string.app_name) + "/video.mp4")
            }
            is VideoRecordEvent.Pause -> { }
            is VideoRecordEvent.Status -> { }
        }
    }
}
```

By debugging on one of the telephones which does not work, I see that the take photo button works well but when he calls the "imageCapture.takePicture" function, nothing happens, no log either in "onError" nor in "onCaptureSuccess". I don't know what to do, I think I have set up the camera correctly and it works perfectly on most phones..

Has anyone run into the same problem? Any solutions for such devices?